# CloudFront distribution with EC2 origin (no ALB)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I set up CF distribution with EC2 origin for dynamic content.
When I use the CF URL, it shows me the website, and it's secure, and everything looks okay, which means Get request is working, but I click on some links similar save or next then I got a 403 error.
[image: 403 Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EC2 origin need to set as HTTP not https